# Comparing multiple keys in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following nested dictionary:

```
{Cow:{legs:thick, tail:long, milk:good, meat:alright}, Goat:{legs:slender, tail:short, milk:ok, meat:excellent}, Fish:{fins:yes, meat:superb, bones:plenty}}
```

My goal is to compare outer keys (Cow, Goat and Fish) and check if their inner keys match or do not match. Ideally I should get:

```
Cow legs: thick 
Goat legs: slender

Cow tail: long
Goat tail: short

Cow milk: good 
Goat milk: ok

Cow meat: alright
Goat meat: excelent
Fish meat: superb

Fish fins: yes
Fish bones: plenty
```

The problem for me is that I cannot yet figure out how to compare inner keys across multiple dictionaries.

I can unpack the nested dict in a traditional way as so:

```
for outerkeys, innerdicts in nestedDict:
      #but here I'm stuck on how to process multiple inner dictionaries
      #to extract matching (and unmatching) keys.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you want to group by the "category" (e.g. "legs", "tail", "meat"), which is the key of the inner dictionary.

then you can iterate the new dictionary and list outputs in the format you wish:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

in_dic = {"Cow": {"legs": "thick", "tail": "long", "milk": "good", "meat": "alright"},
          "Goat": {"legs": "slender", "tail": "short", "milk": "ok", "meat": "excellent"},
          "Fish": {"fins": "yes", "meat": "superb", "bones": "plenty"}}


result_by_category = defaultdict(list)

for animal, categories in in_dic.items():
    for category, value in categories.items():
        result_by_category[category].append((animal, value))

for category, values in result_by_category.items():
    for animal, value in values:
        print('{} {}: {}'.format(animal, category, value))
    print('')
```

output is exactley:

> Cow legs: thick
>   Goat legs: slender
>
> Cow tail: long
>   Goat tail: short
>
> Cow milk: good
>   Goat milk: ok
>
> Cow meat: alright
>   Goat meat: excellent
>   Fish meat: superb
>
> Fish fins: yes
>
> Fish bones: plenty

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by building a list with reorganized key/values using a comprehension:

```
animals = {"Cow": {"legs": "thick", "tail": "long", "milk": "good", "meat": "alright"},
          "Goat": {"legs": "slender", "tail": "short", "milk": "ok", "meat": "excellent"},
          "Fish": {"fins": "yes", "meat": "superb", "bones": "plenty"}}

triples   = [(trait,animal,value) for animal,traits in animals.items() for trait,value in traits.items()]

lineBreak = {min(triples)[0]}
for trait,animal,value in sorted(triples):
    if not(trait in lineBreak or lineBreak.add(trait)): print("")
    print(f"{animal} {trait}: {value}")
```

...

```
Fish bones: plenty

Fish fins: yes

Cow legs: thick
Goat legs: slender

Cow meat: alright
Fish meat: superb
Goat meat: excellent

Cow milk: good
Goat milk: ok

Cow tail: long
Goat tail: short
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with `grouby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

nested_dict = {
    "Cow": {"legs": "thick", "tail": "long", "milk": "good", "meat": "alright"},
    "Goat": {"legs": "slender", "tail": "short", "milk": "ok", "meat": "excellent"},
    "Fish": {"fins": "yes", "meat": "superb", "bones": "plenty"},
}

refactored_items = (
    (k1, k2, v2) for k1, v1 in nested_dict.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()
)
sorted_refactored_items = sorted(refactored_items, key=itemgetter(1))
for _, g in groupby(sorted_refactored_items, key=itemgetter(1)):
    print("\n".join(f"{a} {b}: {c}" for a, b, c in g))
    print("")
```

output:

```
Fish bones: plenty

Fish fins: yes

Cow legs: thick
Goat legs: slender

Cow meat: alright
Goat meat: excellent
Fish meat: superb

Cow milk: good
Goat milk: ok

Cow tail: long
Goat tail: short
```